# Compiler error: Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

Tags: c++, oop

I am having issues compiling my program due to an error with const char *. This is my first time using it and I can't wrap my head around it. Even if it isn't the issue with the code could someone link or explain const char *? Thank you!

I've tried changing different char data types to const char but that isn't working. I've tried looking up in different areas prior to posting this but none of them that I have found are working with methods.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


class Card
{
    public:
        Card();
        Card(int, char);
        
        void setCard(int, const char);
        
        int getFace();
        
        const char getSuit();
        
        void displayCard();
        
    private:
        int faceValue;
        char suitValue[9];
        
};


int main()
{
    //Set the seed value for the random number generator
srand(11);

//Test 1: Constructors and displayCard method

//Create the 3 Card objects

Card firstCard;
Card secondCard;
Card thirdCard = Card( 13, "Spades" );

//Display the 3 objects

cout << "Test 1: Constructors and displayCard method" << endl << endl
     << "  The first card is the ";
firstCard.displayCard();

cout << "." << endl << endl << "  The second card is the ";
secondCard.displayCard();

cout << "." << endl << endl << "  The third card is the ";
thirdCard.displayCard();


//Test 2: setCard method on the first object

cout << endl << endl << endl << "Test 2: setCard method" << endl << endl;

//Change the first card to the Jack of Hearts

firstCard.setCard( 11, "Hearts" );

cout << "  Change the first card to the Jack of Hearts. It is now the ";
firstCard.displayCard();


//Test 3: setCard method on the second object

cout << endl << endl << endl << "Test 3: setCard method with invalid values" << endl << endl;

//Try to change the second card using face of -5 and suit of ""

secondCard.setCard( -5, "" );

cout << "  The second card should be the Ace of Hearts. It is now the ";
secondCard.displayCard();

//Try to change the first card using face of 16 and suit of "Candles"

firstCard.setCard( 16, "Candles" );

cout << endl << endl << "  The first card should be the Ace of Hearts. It is now the ";
firstCard.displayCard();



//Test 4: getFace and getSuit methods on the third object

//Change the third card to 3 of Clubs
thirdCard.setCard( 3, "Clubs" );

cout << endl << endl << endl << "Test 4: getFace and getSuit methods" << endl << endl;

cout << "  The third card should have a face value of 3. It is "
     << thirdCard.getFace() << endl
     << "  The suit value should be Clubs. It is " << thirdCard.getSuit() << endl;

    
    return 0;
}


Card::Card()
{
    faceValue = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    
    int stringValue = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    
    switch(stringValue)
    {
        case 1: 
                strcpy(suitValue, "Clubs");
                break;
                
        case 2:
                strcpy(suitValue, "Diamonds");
                break;
                
        case 3:
                strcpy(suitValue, "Hearts");
                break;
                
        case 4:
                strcpy(suitValue, "Spades");
                break;
                
        default:
                cout << "Your string random number generator is broken";
    }
}


Card::Card(int face, char suit)
{
    setCard(int newFace, const char newSuit[]);
}


void setCard(int newFace, const char newSuit[])
{
    int hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs;
    
    if(newFace > 0 and newFace < 14)
    {
        faceValue = newFace;
    }
    else
    {
        faceValue = 1;
    }
    
    hearts = strcmp(suitValue, newSuit);
    diamonds = strcmp(suitValue, newSuit);
    spades = strcmp(suitValue, newSuit);
    clubs = strcmp(suitValue, newSuit);
    
    if(hearts == 0 or diamonds == 0 or spades == 0 or clubs == 0)
    {
        strcpy(suitValue, newSuit);
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(suitValue, newSuit["Hearts"], 9);
    }
    
}


int Card::getFace()
{
    return faceValue;
}


const char * Card::getSuit()
{
    return suitValue;
}


void displayCard()
{
    switch(faceValue)
    {
        case 1: 
                cout << "Ace of " << suitValue << endl;
                break;
                
        case 11:
                cout << "Jack of " << suitValue << endl;
                break;
                
        case 12:
                cout << "Queen of " << suitValue << endl;
                break;
                
        case 13:
                cout << "King of " << suitValue << endl;
                break;
                
        default:
                cout << faceValue << " of " << suitValue << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: The compiler will tell you the line where this error occurs. You posted way too much code and did not practice good indentation making the code more difficult to read.

Comment: Your `void setCard(int, const char);`  function takes a single character in the second parameter not a string literal so `firstCard.setCard( 16, "Candles" );` wont work. It needs `firstCard.setCard( 16, 'C' );`

Comment: `newSuit["Hearts"]` is invalid, do you just want `"Hearts"`?

Comment: I was able to fix a lot of the issues by changing up the class to:
```
class Card
{
 public:
  Card();
  Card(int, const char[]);
  
  void setCard(int, const char[]);
  
  int getFace();
  
  const char * getSuit();
  
  void displayCard();
  
 private:
  int faceValue;
  char suitValue[9];
  
};
```

The rest of the issues were small things I accidentally overlooked when trying to fix the previous error

Comment: Your code would be much cleaner and simpler if you used `std::string` instead of char arrays / c-strings. I assume you are forced to not use std::string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructors your face value parameter is of the `char` type (one single character). But when you are calling said constructor you give a string (in c a string is an array of characters thus a `char *`). Because you are working in C++ I would recomend on using the string datatype.